# Should I Add .cvsignore file to CVS?

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

Every time I ignore something in IntelliJ, it asks if I want to add my .cvsignore file to CVS.  To me, this seems like a bad idea.  What if other team members have their project set up differently and they need to ignore different files?  Is there any good reason to put the .cvsignore files in CVS?

Comment: It's a common practice to share ignore files via VCS. Subversion stores it as properties instead of separate files so its users have no choice. Git users normally share the `.gitignore` file. CVS users (if they still exist) also do this.

Answer (score 2):

Background for the uninformed: .cvsignore is a file that tells CVS which files or directories to ignore in a CVS version controlled project. If you don't have the .cvsignore file, an IDE may add it to your project files so that your IDE's configuration is not added to source control the next time you check in. This is good because you don't want to push your personal IDE config onto other developers on your project.

Checking in your .cvsignore file is personal preference, but you may want to check with your team first.

Other developers on your project may have different IDEs and different local files that they want to ignore. If all of you add your personal ignore preferences to the .cvsignore file, you could have it already set up for the next developer. This is a good thing, and this is why checking the file in to your repository generally makes the most sense.

You can see how common this practice is by searching open source repositories. [GitHub has .gitignore files](https://github.com/search?q=.gitignore), for example.

The only thing to be aware of is how your project is deployed - you don't necessarily want this file on a production web server or shipped with your software.